# What should be the value of the sku field when creating Azure NAT Gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, nat, sku

I want to create a NAT gateway and there is a parameter called **SKU** is there in the list of parameters. Here is the code for the same

```
$nat = @{
        ResourceGroupName = $coreResourceGroupName
        Name = $natGatewayName
        Sku = 'Standard'
        Location = $location
        PublicIpAddress = $publicIP
    }
$natGateway = New-AzNatGateway @nat
```

Now I am wondering whether I can give ***'Premium'*** in place of ***'Standard'*** for the ***Sku*** field. I have googled and seen multiple examples, but everywhere I see they are using ***'Standard'*** only.

So what are the acceptable values of the paramenter ***'Sku'*** while creating NAT gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
So what are the acceptable values of the paramenter _**'Sku'**_ while creating NAT gateway?
```

Yes, **NAT** is only compatible with **standard** SKU public IP, public IP prefix, and load balancer resources.
It is not supported to work with basic and other **SKU's**.

You can refer this MSFT-[Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/nat-gateway/nat-gateway-resource#limitations) for limitations.

You can also refer to this Terraform-[Document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/nat_gateway#:%7E:text=sku_name%20%2D%20(Optional)%20The%20SKU%20which%20should%20be%20used.%20At%20this%20time%20the%20only%20supported%20value%20is%20Standard.%20Defaults%20to%20Standard.) which is a wrapper over azure powershell where it's clearly mentioned that NAT SKU field supports **Standard** only.